# How to start freerdp fullscreen on second monitor

Tags: multi-monitor, freerdp, xfreerdp

when I log in to a Windows Computer with

```
xfreerdp -v computer -u user --workarea -f
```

the full screen window always appears on the first of my two monitors.
Is it possible to tell freerdp to start on the second monitor or maybe to move the window? The standard KDE window moving with Alt+Click does not work with the freerdp window.

Searching on the internet, I only found examples regarding multi monitoring with multiple remote screens. But I just want to select the local screen displaying the remote session.

I am using freerdp 1.2.0 under Gentoo Linux with KDE 4.14.3.

Addition:

I am not using different X displays. I have a multi monitor setup with randr, `xrandr` outputs the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y     axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   ...
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y     axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   ...
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 15):

Get the monitor number (or numbers) you wish to full screen rdp:

```
xfreerdp /monitor-list
```

Start full screen on monitor:

```
xfreerdp /monitors:2 /multimon /v:<host>
```

Or full screen multiple monitors:

```
xfreerdp /monitors:1,2 /multimon /v:<host>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `xfreerdp /monitor-list` to check detected monitors, and `xfreerdp /monitors:1` to use second monitor.

Comment: Partially worked for me (Mint 17.1, FreeRDP version 2.0.0-dev from nightly builds May 11 2017) in that the fullscreen window appeared correctly sized for monitor 1 but on monitor 0. CTRL-ALT-ENTER toggled to window mode, then dragging to monitor 1 and CTRL-ALT-ENTER to toggle back to fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

The `DISPLAY` environment variable can be used to reach the screens of a multi-desktop system.

`DISPLAY=:0.1 xfreerdp ...` will probably solve your problem. `0.0` would be your first screen, `0.1` is your second.

Answer (score 1):

Use `devilspie2` to automate moving the window to the desired location upon opening. For instance, this config *ought* to do what you want:

```lua
if ( string.find(get_window_name(), 'FreeRDP', 1, true) ~= nil ) then
    undecorate_window()
   x, y, width, height = get_window_geometry();
    set_window_geometry(1920,0,width,height);
    maximize();
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `xprop -root` you can get the parent window id i.e.: `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x2e00004` If you run this `xprot -root` in a terminal on the screen where you want the xfreerdp session than you can start the xfreerdp with `xfreerdp -X <id>` from any screen you want and the window will be created on the screen with the id you selected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I think your command returns the X display. Since I am running a single X server with multiple monitors it returns the same number, no matter on which screen I move the terminal. I should have made this clear in the question, sorry.

Comment: I see what you mean. I got the same when I move the window to another display. Try to have your mouse on the other screen while starting a terminal from the menu. In my case the XID differs when I do that.

Comment: This is not what you are looking for. The xfreerdp session will be embedded into a window from which you use the id. For example the terminal window you previous have moved to another screen.